# Azure Front Door and custom domain

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault, azure-front-door

I'm trying to configure a custom domain with Azure Front Door Premium because it is the only one that allows me to have a custom domain.

The main issue is the certificate. I have my own SSL certificate. Azure Front Door Premium allows to select an SSL certificate only from an Azure Key Vault. So, I created one and I added the certificate. Fine. When I try to add the new domain with this screen

[image]

I can select a Secret from the list. To add a certificate, now I have to add a secret in Azure Front Door from Azure Key Vault. So, I open the **Secret** I select the certificate and click Add.

[image]

Unfortunately, I get an error

> Failed to create the secret 'azuksch-CelloSSL-latest'. Error: We don't have permission to access this secret. Go to "Access policies" in your Key Vault account to give Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-Cdn permission to get secrets.

Following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https#code-try-1), I have to add the Azure Front Door to my Azure Active Directory with this command

```
az ad sp create --id ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037 --role Contributor
```

but the command doesn't work. I have to remove the last part of the command because `role` is not recognised.

[image]

So, I run

```
az ad sp create --id ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037
```

but I have the same issue when I try to add the secret in Azure Front Door. I googled a bit and I found that I have to run another command for Azure Front Door Premium

```
az ad sp create --id 205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8
```

[image]

and selected all the options for all three dropdown list. Now, I have a lot of Access policies

[image]

Result: I always get the same error

> Failed to create the secret 'azuksch-CelloSSL-latest'. Error: We don't have permission to access this secret. Go to "Access policies" in your Key Vault account to give Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-Cdn permission to get secrets.

Can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service principal that you initially created using id `ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037` is for ***Azure Front Door*** not for ***Azure Front Door Premium.***

So, it won’t give permissions for ***Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-Cdn.*** The documentation that you are following is also related to ***Azure Front Door*** not ***Azure Front Door Premium***.

As mentioned in this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-https-custom-domain#register-azure-front-door):

> Registering service principal for Azure Front Door can only done **once per tenant**.

So, even you created service principal again using this id `205478c0-bd83-4e1b-a9d6-db63a3e1e1c8` it won’t work as far as I understand. Try deleting the first service principal that you created using id `ad0e1c7e-6d38-4ba4-9efd-0bc77ba9f037`

Also, please check below note from **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-https-custom-domain#prerequisiteshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-https-custom-domain#prerequisites)**:

> ***Azure Front Door Standard/Premium (Preview)*** is currently in **public preview**. This preview version is provided without a service level agreement, and it's **not recommended** for production workloads. Certain features might **not be supported** or might have constrained capabilities.

As it is still in preview, some features won’t work. So, for the workaround you can make use of **Azure Front Door**.  To know how to add custom domain with **Azure Front Door**, go through this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https) if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Front Door Standard/Premium is no longer in Public Preview but has graduated to General Availability.

I can also confirm that you can indeed register both the Classic and Standard/Premium Service Principal with your tenant and grant them access to [image: Access policies showing both Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor and Microsoft.AzureFrontDoor-CDN]

And still have Front Door Standard/Premium add certificates to the Secret store and assign them to domains.